These boundary homomorphisms are represented as matrices: How do I compute the image and homology groups induced by them?
I'm implementing my own program for topological data analysis (TDA). I'm pretty familiar with the basic theory of algebraic topology, so my issue is mainly regarding the implementation side of things.
From this UPenn paper, page 6:

Let’s begin with a familiar matrix that records node membership within edges. This is a #nodes $\times$ #edges binary matrix with a 1 in position $i,j$ if the $i^{th}$ node is involved in the $j^{th}$ edge (in simplicial complex terms we would say 0-simplex $\{v_i\}$ is a face of 1-simplex $\{v_i, v_j\}$). We will call this matrix $\partial_1$. Recall that any matrix is a linear map between vector spaces. Here we are mapping from the vector space formed by assigning one basis element per edge to the vector space created from basis elements corresponding to nodes. These vector spaces are called the first and zeroth chain groups, $C_1$ and $C_0$, respectively, and their elements (vectors) are also called 1- or 0-chains. For simplicity in computations, we use vector spaces with binary coefficients so that all vectors record "0" or "1" in slots and vector addition proceeds via binary arithmetic: edges and vertices are either "off" or "on".
This matrix houses a large amount of structural information. First, if we send a 1-chain (vector) corresponding to one edge through this map it is sent to its two end nodes, or its boundary. Not surprisingly, $\partial_1$ is called the boundary operator. Second, note that we can make 1-chains in $C_1$ corresponding to paths...

Finding the kernel of this boundary homomorphism seems to make sense; I can use any nullspace package and obtain the solution without any major headache. Finding the kernel for the edge case $\partial_0$ is also easy to do with my prior knowledge of homology. The only other edge case is when my matrix resembles a column vector, but I think I've correctly deduced that the kernel of that matrix is just the zero element.
The issue for me is taking images and then taking quotients by images. Following from the paper example, use unital values to represent the integral basis for the chain groups. Have some $m \times n$ boundary matrix $\partial$. I currently compute $\text{img } \partial$ as such: have an $n$-dimensional unital vector $U =  1 \oplus \cdots \oplus 1$. I compute the image as $$ \text{img } \partial = \partial U$$ However, this is my homebrew method, and I don't know if it is the correct way to do this. For instance, I'm having trouble with the following case: Have an abstract simplicial complex $K = \left \{p_1 , p_2 , \{ p_1, p_2 \} \right \}$. Then the corresponding first boundary matrix for $K$ and the kernel of the zeroth boundary matrix for $K$  take the following forms:
$$ \partial_1 = \left[ \begin{array} & 1 \\ 1 \end{array}\right] , \quad \ker \partial_0 = \left[ \begin{array} & 1 \\ 1 \end{array}\right]$$
Now, the unital vector $U$ corresponding to $\partial_1$ will be the chain group corresponding to this single edge, which is represented in this form by just $1$. Then from the rules I've set up:
$$\text{img } \partial_1 = \left[ \begin{array} & 1 \\ 1 \end{array}\right] (1) = \left[ \begin{array} & 1 \\ 1 \end{array}\right]$$
but then I would expect the quotient group of this operation to be $$ H_0 (K) = (\ker \partial_0) \div (\text{img } \partial_1) $$
which in this simple case I naively interpret as removing unital entries of the vector corresponding to $\text{img } \partial_1$ from the vector $\ker \partial_0$. But this would mean then that $$H_0 (K) = \left[ \begin{array} & 0 \\ 0 \end{array}\right]  \approx 0$$ which contrasts with my expectation that $$ H_0 (K) \approx \mathbb Z$$

(a) Am I correctly calculating the image and quotient in this case? I believe I'm not, but I don't know what I'm doing wrong. How do I fix this process?
I wouldn't be surprised if there's some gap in my linear algebra knowledge that's throwing my process off. Thanks in advance.

The kernel of $\partial_0$ is two-dimensional (it's everything).

@JHF Agreed, but I already wrote that in the problem statement. It's written as $\mathbb Z \oplus \mathbb Z$ in the more theoretical approach, but here I wrote $\ker \partial_0 = 1 \oplus 1$ as the column matrix. The challenge is figuring out the images of these maps. I thought looking at the column space would work, but I wasn't figuring out how to avoid getting a two-dimensional image from looking at these matrices, even though the paper suggests you do that.
